# xcode Unsupported URL when sending request

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, http

I am trying to send a GET Http Request to my computer that runs an Apache server.
When I send the request from XCODE to X.X.X.X\my_script.php using sendSynchronousRequest I get a response - Unsupported URL.
However, if I try to connect to this address using my browser it works fine.

Any suggestions? does it not support an address which contains IP?

Answer (score 0):

Change slash in your request: `X.X.X.X/my_script.php`

Comment: You should show your code when you ask that kind of question.